# How to display sencha touch slider with horizontal values

Tags: extjs, slider

Please have a look on the following image.

[image]

How to display values along slider like bars with values ( Extremely unlikely, Neutral and Extremely likely ) as displaying in above image ?

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain this is no built-in functionality for this. Make sure to always check out the [Sencha Market](https://market.sencha.com/) in case someone made a custom component/extension/plugin though just in case.

My recommendation would be to create your own custom component, which should be simply a container with a vbox layout. First item should be your slider, second item probably another container with a hbox layout. Put your slider values as items under the hbox container with some custom CSS. Take it one step further if you want, and maybe in your constructor/initialize function add a listener to the slider and when it changes you can do something with the labels to indiciate the selected value.